# Large traffic by empty user agent

Tags: php, themes, opencart, user-agent

After installing new opencart theme by "themeburn" site traffic increased.
Most of traffic generated by empty user agent.

[image]

[image: Image 2]

Looking logs I found out the sourse of requests with empty user agent :

> 168.1.75.14 - - [11/Mar/2018:07:08:31 -0500] "GET /image/cache/tb/main.b32853840deeea469a0caceda1189373.css HTTP/1.0"
>   200 571763 "-" "-"

This ip is my site's one, so i can't just block it using htaccess.
All requests from my ip with empty user agent are similar and they all request this main.css.

Is this situation normal and its just theme feature, or i should search for a problem?

Comment: that's a weird behaviour, maybe some issue with theme `config`. It seems to be wasting your Bandwidth & server resources, maybe caching that `css` file using `.htaccess` until you figure out the cause of this `issue` might help. Also contact the `Theme Developer` to check if they've ever faced this issue with other customers.

Comment: I would think also this could be a _malicious_ behavior, to do an HTTP request on the same site, instead of just reading the file with a php function it must be coded to act like that, the program needs: 1) get the full domain URL, 2) calculate the relative path of the public folder tree of the web server, 3) use a lib like cURL to send the request. It can't be just an accident.